# How is it possible that when we are in heaven we will be perfect and sinless, if the angels sinned while they were in heaven?

Tags: contradiction, sin, angels, heaven

I've been wondering this for a few days (please correct my reasoning if faulty):

How is it possible that in heaven we will have a perfect body and be without sin, if the angels themselves sinned while they were in heaven?

If it is possible to sin in heaven what is the basis for the idea that we will ever be free from sin?

Are angels sinning in heaven and being free from sin in heaven contradictory ideas?

Comment: Hi Sergon24 welcome to the site. I polished up your question a little bit, but am happy to roll back the changes if you don't like them. On this site we require a text to evaluate.  Can you specify what biblical passage(s) you have in mind?

Comment: I suggest Jude 1:6 for a text indicating that angels fell from heaven. Romans 5:12 for evidence that sin entered the world through Adam.

Comment: They sinned because they made the wrong choice willfully. Good Q.

Comment: trying to formulate the nature and possibilities of the heavens and angels in detail is speculative and not possible.

Comment: @Michele16 maybe you didn't understand the question correctly, I just wanted to know if once we go to heaven we will still be subject to sin

Comment: The question is opinion based as there is no Biblical scripture referenced to discuss.

Comment: I have always wondered if God gave us free will in this lifetime and we can choose to sin and do sin, why would we stop sinning when we get to heaven? Won't we still have free will in heaven? If so, why is there no sinning in heaven? And, if we don't have free will in heaven, then wouldn't we all just be robots? Will we have to worship God day and night or will we be free to do other stuff besides having chapel services day and night?

Comment: Remember that Heaven is also part of creation (Gen 1:1), not something inherently eternal like its Creator. There will be "a new Heaven and a new Earth," Revelation tells us. Earth and Heaven will both be redeemed. Thus the downfall that was possible in the old heaven will presumably not be possible in the new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the expression "being in heaven" in the sense of "enjoying the beatific vision", the angels after their creation were **not** "in heaven". In Catholic theological terms, they had been infused with the supernatural gifts of sanctifiying grace and charity through which they had "become partakers of the divine nature" (2 Pe 1:4) but they still were **not** seeing God "face to face" (1 Cor 13:12), "as He is" (1 John 3:2).

It was in that initial state of grace but still not of glory that the angels had to choose between loving and serving God or rebelling against Him. Those who chose to love and serve God were "raised" by God to the beatific vision, in which they can no longer sin.

Comment: Thank you very much this was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Understanding for specific questions comes from different places in the Bible, keep reading seeking God and you will find. Here are a few of those places and how they fit together for your question.

God gave all created spiritual beings free will, as he did not want robots, but beings to choose to worship and serve him, In order to care for and show us his love, he put each spirit in a separate container/body. Before the fall, the first man was innocent, filled neither with light (good) nor darkness (evil). Angels were created with light and is why they have no redemption when they used their free will and fell. For us, we must first be saved Romans 9:10. We are not this earthly flesh container which is passing away, we are the spirit/soul inside John 6:63, this body is like your clothes. When it goes away you are what is inside. Both our spirit and body are fallen though, and when saved, our spirit only is renewed/cleaned/reborn but our body remains fallen Romans 8:1-11. So a war goes on inside us while we remain here Romans 7:14-25. So we must as best we are able to resist the urges of the body/flesh Romans 6:1-12. Even saved we still sin because God's standard is higher than we on our own can reach, which is why he gave us of his son Yeshua (Jesus). Once saved our soul is clean and sin is no longer counted against us. However we are not nor will be sin free here and must continue to resist sin, acknowledge our sins to and ask God through his son to help us resist and forgive our slip ups.

So on to perfection, we have the son of God as our example and template Hebrews 2:14-18 and 5:8-9. The understanding given to me is that perfection for us is the cleaning of our spirit (being saved) and the suffering/enduring of trials and tribulations here without losing our trust in God. The new body comes with resurrection see 1 Corinthians 15:42-44. The first resurrection doesn’t happen until the second coming Revelation 20:5-6. As to heaven, until Yeshua completed God’s work and was resurrected, both Satan and his fallen angels resided in heaven until they were overcome by the blood of Yeshua (Lamb) and were permanently cast out of heaven Revelation 12: 7-12; John 12:31; John 14:30; Job 1:6-12. When our body dies it returns to dust and releases our perfected spirit, we reside in God’s throne room on the sea of glass worshiping God day and night until the second coming of Yeshua Revelation 7:9-17. All of this creation goes away both heaven and earth Revelation 20:11 only the created spirit beings remain and will either go into the lake of fire or live with God and his son on the new earth in the New Jerusalem Revelation 21:1-8

God Bless, hope this helps. Most of the Bible, especially NT is written for our spirits not our flesh body, again John 6:63.

Comment: It would be helpful if your answer was broken up into individual paragraphs. People will generally pass over a "wall of text" as you have written. I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s section on answering questions.

Comment: thank you for your answer you have been very clear, only one thing I have not been able to understand, in your opinion so when we will be in heaven we will still be able to sin?

Comment: No,as we only sin while in this fallen body here. Your soul is cleansed when you meet the requirements of Romans 10:9. Only the cleansed souls through the washing of the blood go to God's throne room in this heaven to worship him day and night until the second coming Revelation 7:9-17. The body or tent as Peter calls it in 2 Peter 1:13-14 we are in now returns to this earth. The first resurrection in the new body is not until second coming Revelation 20:4-6. and that will be the spiritual body free of sin.

Answer (score 1):

The answer hinges on the difference between sinlessness and perfection. God created all spiritual beings (including both humans and angels) sinless. Humans fell, and so did at least some of the angels. These beings were all sinless prior to their fall, but not perfect.

Perfection, on the other hand, may be defined as ["corresponding to an ideal standard."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfect)  A perfect being in this sense would never separate from God's will. In the Garden of Eden neither the serpent nor Adam and Eve could have been perfect before the Fall, although they may have been sinless.

Human beings attain heaven through the process of salvation, through which they are restored to the status of sinless sons and daughters of God. Having known sin, the are perfected through their faith. In some theologies, perfection also involves spiritual growth: cooperating with God by overcoming various trials and aligning one's will with God's. Either way, such a person has not only been redeemed from sin, but has been made perfect through God's grace. Thus, Paul wrote:

> I appeal to you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, to
> present your bodies as a living sacrifice, holy and acceptable to God,
> which is your spiritual worship. Do not be conformed to this world but
> be transformed by the renewal of your mind, that you may prove what is
> the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect. (Rom 12:1-2)

As mentioned, angels are sinless, but not necessarily perfect. It is perhaps in this sense that Paul also wrote in 1 Corinthians 6:3 "Do you not know that we are to judge angels?"

**Conclusion: being sinless is not the same as being perfect. Sinless beings can fall, as some of the angels did. Perfected beings do not fall. Thus we can be assured that those of us who attain heaven will not follow the example of those angelic beings "that did not keep their own position but left their proper dwelling..." (Jude 1:6)**

Comment: thank you for your answer you have been very clear, only one thing I have not been able to understand, in your opinion so when we will be in heaven we will still be able to sin?

Comment: Perfect humans are not tempted to sin, so they might have the freedom to do so, but their bond of love with God is so great that they would not even consider it. So not in 'Heaven' if we are talking about the realm of perfected/sanctified  humans. But personally I believe that even not-perfect (or not saved) humans dwell in the spiritual world, and such people can sin, just as the angels did.

Answer (score 1):

In the book of Ezekiel, there is a description of the fall of Lucifer (King of Tyrus), that is spoken of in a parable. He is with God and is seated above his throne, and God describes how He made him so beautiful with all the gems and precious stones.

Now the fall of Lucifer made him subject to an eternal judgement which has been sealed in the prophetic book of Revelations.

We humans have a choice, in fact God allows man to fall over and over. Proverbs 24:16-18 King James Version, says a righteous man falls seven times over. In the life of David, as recorded in the bible there are seven instances of his fall (that I have counted) including all the instances of lies, adultery, murder, etc... God is still with David until the end as he is a man after the heart of God, he is anointed and chosen by God.

So I will ask you this, why God allows man to fall over and over and still have the availability of redemption through Christ? And angels who have sinned against God, only once, like Lucifer's fall from heaven - have an eternal judgement... Why is there no redemption for satan?

The answer, I believe is because there was no source or temptation for Lucifer to fall, they were in the presence of the almighty. Human's on the other other hand live in a fallen world, where their are many temptations and seductions, their are spirituals powers of wickedness (Ephesians 6) that lead to our fall.

Also notice, the tree of knowledge of Good and Evil, contains the seed of the idea of the fall of man. Man had to fall in order to foreshadow the fall in the heavenlies, so there may be redemption of man one day through Jesus (the tree of life). The redeemed man is no more innocent, he knows Good and Evil having endured unto the very end all the temptations of life and gaining the knowledge of sin/evil. Now willfully having chosen God, there is no possibility for him to fall again, because he knows the end.

Ultimately, the mystery of God is too big for any man to know, so this is a filtered down version of what I have come to understand.

Comment: thank you for your answer you have been very clear, only one thing I have not been able to understand, in your opinion so when we will be in heaven we will still be able to sin?

Comment: @Sergon24 In my opinion - No. There are verses about justification vs. sanctification. As others have answered in this thread that after being justified by the sacrifice of Jesus, we need to strive towards being holy, perfect. So, the inner man or the spirit of man, is reborn with Christ, we are to keep on renewing our mind as the body and soul are still "weak". So, if we strive towards sanctification, we are already gaining the knowledge of evil/sin and how it leads to death. 
Have to break it down due to character limit...

Comment: There are also concepts of spiritual time and time as we experience it. The Bible is a prophetic book. And God is beyond our time, so the prophecies that happen in the realm of God (which cannot be reverted or cancelled by God) have in a way already happened. So, the end of the story, when death, and all the influences of evil are destroyed, there cannot be any evil/sin. I believe in heaven it would not be possible to even imagine sinning against God as even the desire to sin would not be there.

Comment: Why because, desires are given by God, they are perverted in this world because of influence of evil. Love degrades to lust, service/charity degrades to the desire to take forcefully/steal/lie/murder. The degradation is because of the fall. The redemption fulfills the story of fall by destroying the sources of evil.

Comment: ok now i understand, thank you very much for your help and your time

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between being *able* to sin and being *willing* to sin.  That difference is crucial.

When the angels sinned in Heaven, it was a first in God's universe.  It had never happened before.  Everyone was ignorant of sin and its disastrous results.  They could not foresee the full effects of it.

God held a council in Heaven, granting each angel the choice of whether they would follow Lucifer (who became Satan) in his desires to lead a new sin-based government, or whether they would remain loyal to God under the leadership of Michael, the archangel (see Jude 1:9).

While God explained how sin would result, the angels had no experiential knowledge of this, and were left to make a faith-choice.  God gave them liberty to do so, and about a third of the angels (also referenced as "stars") elected to follow Lucifer in his rebellion against God's government.

> <sup>3</sup>And there appeared another wonder in heaven; and behold a
> great red dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and seven crowns
> upon his heads. <sup>4</sup>And his tail drew the third part of the
> stars of heaven, and did cast them to the earth: . . . <sup>7</sup>And
> there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the
> dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels, <sup>8</sup>And
> prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven.
> <sup>9</sup>And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent,
> called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was
> cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.
> (Revelation 12:3-9, KJV)

It was *after* this war in Heaven that the war was continued on Earth.  Adam and Eve, wittingly or not, chose to follow the rebel leader, and the rest is history.  We have all inherited sin from our parents, and Satan has ready access to us with his temptations.

In Heaven, the Tempter will no longer have access to us.  Furthermore, we will have been amply inoculated against sin.  We will have zero desire to return to the miserable affliction of sin, even though we will always have full freedom of choice and could, theoretically, sin again if we chose.  We simply will never again choose sin--of our own free will, educated by a lifetime of experience with its woes.

> What do ye imagine against the LORD? he will make an utter end:
> **affliction shall not rise up the second time.** (Nahum 1:9, KJV)